# Django SimpleUploadedFile is not being sent

Tags: python, django, request, missing-data, django-testing

I'm developing Django application and wrote a test that checks if view method acts correctly. I need to send some data in request, including the image file.
In my case:

```
def setUp(self):
   ...
   self.image_file = SimpleUploadedFile("test_image.jpg", b"file_content",
                                         content_type='image/jpeg')
   ...

def test_save_image_instance(self):
   ...
    files = {'image': self.image_file}
    response = self.client.post(endpoint, data=data, files=files)
    # assertions there
   ...
```

I double-checked, everything is correct, there is `SimpleUploadedFile` instance in `file` dictionary.

But in the view `request.FILES` is empty (`<MultiValueDict: {}>`), though `data` was sent correctly. Also, if I look into `request.META` there is `'files': {'image': <SimpleUploadedFile: test_image.jpg (image/jpeg)>}`, which indicates that the file should be there.
Django `CommonMiddleware` is set correctly, type of content in the request is `multipart/form-data`

I tried using `UploadFile` class instead of `SimpleUploadFile`, checking values in different places of the program to find the problem, but it didn't help.

Comment: Solved.
File should be provided in the same dictionary as rest of the data.
So it should look like:
```
data = {
    # some other data
    'image': self.image_file
        }
        response = self.client.post(endpoint, data=data)
```